# Date range query for past 24 hour in Mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, cron

I am setting a **cron** job to collect results from MongoDB database profiler. I'd like to collect results within a 24 hrs period. I plan to run **mongo** command with **javascript**.

Question is, in **Mongo shell**, how do I write a query to find a date range from 24 hrs ago? Such as:

```
db.system.profile.find({
    "timestamp" : {
        $lte : <current date & time>,
        $gt : <date & time 24 hrs ago>
    }
})
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Found answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/subtract-days-from-a-date-in-javascript

```
db.system.profile.find({ 
  "timestamp" : { 
    $lt: new Date(), 
    $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1))
  }   
})
```

Comment: Works in Compass but i cant get it to work in Atlas.

Answer (score 6):

```js
db.system.profile.find({ 
 "timestamp" : 
    {     
        $gte:   new Date(new Date().setHours(00,00,00)) ,     
        $lt :  new Date(new Date().setHours(23,59,59)) 
   } 
})
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it is different from the code seen in the accepted answer.

Comment: This differs from the accepted answer in that it searches for the whole current day (eg. "Friday"). Conversely, the accepted answer searches for "the last 24 hours".

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.find(
        {$and: 
                [
                { "status.code":"DELIVERY_PENDING"},
                {"status.createdDtm": {$lte: new Date().getTime()-(1*60*60*1000) }}
                ]

        }
        )
```

Comment: You should add details about how this works and why it fixes the problem.

Comment: What's with "DELIVERY_PENDING"?!